# 2D and 3D Tikz pictures side-by-side

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-3dplot, varwidth

Previously I've had problems with 3D Tikz pictures having a lot of whitespace added to one side which was solved by using `\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}`.

Now, however, I'm trying to draw a 2D and 3D picture side-by-side.  I can't just include the two pictures separately in the final document with the `subcaption` package because of journal graphics requirements.  Previously I was generating two separate pdfs of the pictures, then combining them into one pdf (for insertion into the final document) with another .tex file.  This seems like a convoluted way of doing things though.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
\draw[-] (0,2)--(3,2)--(3,4)--(0,4)--cycle;
\draw[-] (0,4)--(3,4)--(3,6)--(0,6)--cycle;
\node at (-0.4,5.7) {{\large a}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{90}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_rotated_coords]

\draw[->, thick] (0,0,0) --++ (20:3);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (60:2);

\draw[dashed] (0,0,-2) circle(2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) circle(2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,2) circle(2);

\node[left] at (0,0,0) {{ $i$}};
\node[right] at (2.2,0.15,-0.05) {{\large {\bf M}}};
\node[below] at (0.5,0.5,0) {{\large $\phi_i$}};

\draw[->] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,3.5);
\node[above] at (0,0,3.5) {{\large $z$}};

\node at (-2,0,3.5) {{\large b}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you compile it as it is, the two tikz pictures align one above the other.  I think that's because of the `varwidth` argument.  If you take that out the pictures are side-by-side but the whitespace associated with the 3D picture appears, so the two are separated by a large gap.

Does anyone know the best way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you explain the problem with the journal, may be we can suggest better solutions

Comment: Copied from below for visibility: The problem with the journal is that they want all figures to be submitted as a single pdf file, even if they contain subfigures. So when I'd normally produce a pdf for each subfigure and put them both into the main document with \begin{figure}\begin{subfigure} etc., I'm having to join the two together so that only one pdf is included in the final document. Did it make sense that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2nd version:**

So the problem seems to include different figures in one pdf file. There are several solutions but as you use `standalone` class and `TiKZ` you just need to include `tikz` as an option to your original example (`\documentclass[tikz,varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}`) and will get a pdf file with as many pages as `tikzpictures`. You can include figures in your text with `\includegraphics[page=...]{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=1]{sensetitol-3}
\subcaption{Subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=2]{sensetitol-3}
\subcaption{Subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

I don't understand the problem you have with the journalgraphics requirements but if you want to place both figures side by side with `varwidth` option one possible solution can be to draw both figures inside the same `tikzpicture` with one of them inside a properly placed `scope`.

Note: `shift` values have been found by trial and error.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{90}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
\draw[-] (0,2)--(3,2)--(3,4)--(0,4)--cycle;
\draw[-] (0,4)--(3,4)--(3,6)--(0,6)--cycle;
\node at (-0.4,5.7) {{\large a}};
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords, xshift=6cm, yshift=2.5cm]
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,0) --++ (20:3);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (60:2);

\draw[dashed] (0,0,-2) circle(2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) circle(2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,2) circle(2);

\node[left] at (0,0,0) {{ $i$}};
\node[right] at (2.2,0.15,-0.05) {{\large {\bf M}}};
\node[below] at (0.5,0.5,0) {{\large $\phi_i$}};

\draw[->] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,3.5);
\node[above] at (0,0,3.5) {{\large $z$}};

\node at (-2,0,3.5) {{\large b}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that worked straight away, many thanks.  The problem with the journal is that they want all figures to be submitted as a single pdf file, even if they contain subfigures.  So when I'd normally produce a pdf for each subfigure and put them both into the main document with ``\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}`` etc., I'm having to join the two together so that only one pdf is included in the final document.  Did it make sense that time?

Comment: @user3087409 See the edited answer, it can help you to produce all figures within one file

Comment: I didn't know about the ``[page= ... ]`` option, that's very useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your pictures into two separate `varwidth` environments to do the trick:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}

\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--(0,2)--cycle;
\draw[-] (0,2)--(3,2)--(3,4)--(0,4)--cycle;
\draw[-] (0,4)--(3,4)--(3,6)--(0,6)--cycle;
\node at (-0.4,5.7) {{\large a}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{varwidth}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{90}{90}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{20}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_rotated_coords]

\draw[->, thick] (0,0,0) --++ (20:3);
\draw[->] (0,0,0) --++ (60:2);

\draw[dashed] (0,0,-2) circle(2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) circle(2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0,2) circle(2);

\node[left] at (0,0,0) {{ $i$}};
\node[right] at (2.2,0.15,-0.05) {{\large {\bf M}}};
\node[below] at (0.5,0.5,0) {{\large $\phi_i$}};

\draw[->] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,3.5);
\node[above] at (0,0,3.5) {{\large $z$}};

\node at (-2,0,3.5) {{\large b}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]